# SQLPLUS is making my script to prompt: Enter value for row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm running the most basic oracle sql script and running it in sqlplus. 
I can't understand why my script stops to prompt me for 'Enter value for row'. Wasn't the FOR LOOP supposed to open the cursor before looping?

The code is:

```
/*
  File: myTest.sql
*/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE UNLIMITED
SET LINESIZE 140
SET PAGESIZE 60
SET ECHO OFF
SET TERM ON
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET SHOW ON
SET VERIFY OFF

SPOOL &1

/* Run Parameters & Variables */
DECLARE
text_line         VARCHAR2(4000);

/* Cursors & Row Types */
CURSOR myCursor IS 
  select spriden_pidm, spriden_id, spriden_first_name, spriden_last_name from spriden where spriden_id = '1234';

myCursorRec       myCursor%ROWTYPE;

/* Main Logic */
BEGIN 
  /* Read through all the entries form our data sources. */
  FOR myCursorRec IN myCursor LOOP
    text_line := text_line + myCursorRec.spriden_last_name; 
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This is the output: ' || text_line || ', ');

END;
/

SPOOL OFF

/* EXIT is needed for Windows environments. */
EXIT
```

And I run it with this command:

```
sqlplus dbuser/userpass@dbserver @myTest MYSPOOL
```

The output looks like this:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production on Wed Feb 7 13:06:51 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2008, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

new: showmode BOTH
old: verify ON
new: verify OFF
Enter value for row: gggggg
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 14


Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
```

Why do I get that 'Enter value for row:' prompt???

Comment: The ORA-06502 - numeric or value error is for the text_line := text_line + myCursorRec.spriden_last_name; Replace + for ||

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because of ampersand, here:

```
/* Cursors & Row Types */
```

Include `SET DEFINE OFF` into the set of your SET commands and then try again.

Or, alternatively, use AND :)

```
/* Cursors and Row Types */
```

Comment: That worked thanks! I thought comments were harmless :/

Comment: @SalvadorValencia It's a quirk of SQL*Plus and if you ask me, a bug :)